# Ternary operator for 3 conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ternary-operator

I have using jsReport lib in different enviroments (Windows, OsX and Linux)

In `Startup.cs` I use this code, to launch library

```
services.AddJsReport(new LocalReporting()
                .UseBinary(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)
                    ? JsReportBinary.GetBinary()
                    : jsreport.Binary.OSX.JsReportBinary.GetBinary()).AsUtility()
            .Create());
```

So if it's not Windows platform, he looking for binary for OSX.

But when somebody will use project on Linux he need to change code to:

```
services.AddJsReport(new LocalReporting()
            .UseBinary(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)
                ? JsReportBinary.GetBinary()
                : jsreport.Binary.Linux.JsReportBinary.GetBinary())
```

How I can write ternary condition for using Windows as main, and if not it will select between OSX and Linux?

Comment: Is there way the OS can be identified? Both posted code snippet has  `OSPlatform.Windows` to check the platform?

Comment: after the ":", in the "if not" part, you can write another ternary operation, checking if it's OSX or Linux, and then returning the corresponding one.

Answer (score 4):

```cs
services.AddJsReport(new LocalReporting()
    .UseBinary(
        RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)
        ? JsReportBinary.GetBinary()
        : RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)
            ? Jsreport.Binary.Linux.JsReportBinary.GetBinary()
            : Jsreport.Binary.OSX.JsReportBinary.GetBinary())
    .Create();
```

But it might be easier just writing 3 `if`s and doing it like so:

```cs
// I don't know the exact type, put the correct one here if it isn't this
JsReportBinary binary;

if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
    binary = JsReportBinary.GetBinary();
else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
    binary = Jsreport.Binary.Linux.JsReportBinary.GetBinary();
else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX)
    binary = Jsreport.Binary.OSX.JsReportBinary.GetBinary());
else
    binary = null;

services.AddJsReport(new LocalReporting().UseBinary(binary).Create());
```

Comment: @EugeneSukh No problem, here to help. Btw I just updated my answer with an alternate (and in my opinion easier to read) way of achieving this. Also don't forget to mark the answer as accepted with the green checkmark if this solved your problem so future viewers can more easily spot it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)
      ? JsReportBinary.GetBinary() :
    RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX) ?
   jsreport.Binary.OSX.JsReportBinary.GetBinary()  : 
   jsreport.Binary.Linux.JsReportBinary.GetBinary())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it, but it will work,

```
services.AddJsReport(new LocalReporting()
                .UseBinary((RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) && JsReportBinary.GetBinary())
                           || (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux) && Jsreport.Binary.Linux.JsReportBinary.GetBinary())
                           || (Jsreport.Binary.OSX.JsReportBinary.GetBinary()))
                .Create();
```

***Benefit:*** we can have any number of conditions.